# PHP sorting a array

Tags: php, arrays

i´ve got this problem:

My inputfile (*.txt):

```
1234;855245;2015-11-02;
1234;21364;2015-11-03;
1234;85456;2015-11-04;
1234;85245;2015-11-05;
1234;815245;2015-11-05;
1234;4524;2015-11-06;
1234;452004;2015-11-06;
1234;4524;2015-11-06;
1234;15000;2015-11-07;
1234;85259;2015-11-08;
1234;58959;2015-11-08;
```

I´d like to sort this file in an array like this:

```
2015-11-04 : 85456
2015-11-05 : 815245
2015-11-06 : 452004
2015-11-07 : 15000
2015-11-08 : 85259
```

Explanation how to sort:

- Today - 4 Days before
- sorted by the earliest date (2015-11-04 to 2015-11-08)
- the biggest index[1] for my date
- when today isn´t in my input file, then look for the last date in my input file after the actually date

I hope you understand, what i mean, and you can help me.

btw. sorry for my very bad english

Comment: you wish to sort the files? or the content inside the file?

Comment: Please explain which solutions you have tried and how they failed.

Comment: @AlexTartan i have add my solution in this question as answer

Comment: @jochen i have add my solution in this question as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your file like this:

```
$arr = Array();
$lines = explode('\n', file_get_contents("file.txt"));
foreach($lines as $line){
    $columns = explode(';', $line);
    while(empty($columns[count($columns) - 1])) array_shift($columns);
    if(count($columns) > 0) array_push($arr, $columns);
}
```

Than you have an multidimensional-array. You have an entry for each line of the file. These entries contains the rows as array.

You can then further process this array on your own:

1. Check each line for its age and delete it if it is too old
2. Sort array with `array_multisort` (see PHP manual)